# Same color looks different between pictures in Photoshop

Tags: colors, photoshop

The color is #dcfbdd

I attached an image and you can see the difference in color below the picture.

The first picture is darker yet when I go into photoshop I'm picking the exact same color and photoshop is telling me it's the exact same color. But even the color panel in photoshop shows 2 different colors for the same hex.

Any ideas on what I could do to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get #C6FCDC for the darker one then #D5FCDB.
I get these hex by using visual studio pipette.

Also change your monitor setting. I get similiar colour too in a brighter monitor.
Hope it helps. So if you see them in darker monitor, you may see the difference.

Comment: I also get different colors when using a color picker in the web browser and in photoshop. It's just that photoshop insists these two colors are the same even though they're clearly not. I'm literally coloring picking one color and paint bucketing it in the other

Comment: Is there any layer above the layer where you put the bucket on?

Comment: I ended up just making the background transparent so that it could end up looking the same as the background.

Comment: Yes, but it's layed out the exact same way in both images

Comment: Try to hide the above layer one by one. It might have not detect the color because the other color is on above layer.